# flex 4 - creationIndex for containers

Tags: flex4

In Flex 3, we can set the following properties in a container object for deferred instantiation:

```
creationPolicy = "queued"
creationIndex = "1" (or "2" or "3" etc.)
```

In Flex 4, for  I can find the creationPolicy property but there is no creationIndex - trying to set the  creationIndex throws a "deprecated" warning but there is no hint on what to use otherwise

Any ideas?

Thanks
- Sami

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find it either, what I ended up doing was creating states for each loading phase and then only including the pieces I wanted to load in that state. When that particular group had finished loading it would fire an event to change to the next loading state.